# How to set default value for input with type of date in jquery repeater?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery.repeater

I use [jquery repeater](https://github.com/DubFriend/jquery.repeater) in my project. When I try set default value for input type date return error:

> jquery.repeater.js:688 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set'
>   of undefined

**Form code:**

```
<form action="" class="repeater" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div data-repeater-list="users">
    <div data-repeater-item>
      <input type="text" name="name"/>
      <input type="email" name="email"/>
      <select name="sex">
        <option value="0" selected>Male</option>
        <option value="1">Female</option>
      </select>
      <input type="date" name="birthday"/>
      <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input id="add" data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add User"/>
</form>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    $('.repeater').repeater({
        defaultValues: {
            'name': 'User',
            'email': 'user@gmail.com',
            'sex': '0',
            'birthday': "1990-09-10"
        },
        show: function () {
            $(this).slideDown();
        },
        hide: function (deleteElement) {
            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
                $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
            }
        },
        ready: function (setIndexes) {

        }
    });
    $('#add').on('click', function(e){
      var users = $('.repeater').repeaterVal();
      console.log(users);
    });
});
```

When I don't set default value then I can't get all fields values.

Comment: can you set the `birthday` default value to `new Date()` and observe if this error still occurring?

Comment: @ymz, I tested but the same mistake was coming back

Comment: 1. remove the `birthday` binding and validate there is no error 2. try to change the input type to `text`.... just for the record: this is a very "old-fashion" way to get data binding... maybe it's time to learn `angular` or `react`

Answer (score 0):

For me I did it the old fashioned way using JQuery

```
 $(".mydiv-item-repeater").length && $(".mydiv-item-repeater").repeater({
            show: function () {
             $(this).find(".select").val(value);
                $(this).slideDown()
            }, hide: function (e) {
                $(this).slideUp(e)
            }
        });
```